# From website to app to website on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, native, hybrid

I'm working on an iOS app some people want to link to from their website.

While I've managed to open my app from a webpage using [schemes](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/), I wonder if, when I'm done with what I have to do in my app, I can switch back to the original website tab in safari.

*To my knowledge* : it is pretty straightforward to open a new page in safari from my app but I don't know if it is possible to get back to the actual original page, just like the ios9 back-to-app button would do.

I could open a new page and close it straight away with some javascript, which would probably display the original page because it's the next one in the tab list... but it doesn't feel right (does it?)

I read stuff about ios9 deep linking, still can't find anything interesting.

Comment: Jus to be clear, you want to open a website INSIDE your app, and after using the website, get back to the app, is that correct?

Comment: Actually, I want to open Safari where I left off. Say you're on a website in safari, you want to pay, it opens a payment app for you, you pay, then you go back to the website where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this is to open Safari using URLScheme. However, (afaik) Safari App doesn't have a url scheme. If the user came to your app from Chrome, than you can use its url scheme

```
Google Chrome has the following two URI schemes: googlechrome:// and googlechromes://
```

iOS 9's back to app button can't be invoked programmatically, so you can't use it as well. However in jailbreaked devices an app can mimic that, maybe that will help you http://theunlockr.com/2015/08/23/enable-back-button-ios-8-video/

> I could open a new page and close it straight away with some
>   javascript, which would probably display the original page because
>   it's the next one in the tab list... but it doesn't feel right (does
>   it?)

It doesn't feel right at all. Because the typical behaviour for turning back to previos (or any other) application among iOS users is pressing home button twice, and selecting the app. Maybe you can simply show a message, and ask user to return Safari.